# Как увеличить значение переменной?

Tags: python

Я написал код и мне выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Users/Rain/Desktop/yazik.py", line 16, in <module>  
    EnterTimes = EnterTimes + 1  
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Весь код:

```
import os  
Code = ""  
NeedStop = "No"  
EnterTimes="0"  
String=""  
AirVar=""  
print (AirVar)  
print ("Devian Language")  
print ("For help type deviancommandes,tap enter 5 times to finish programm")  
while NeedStop == "No":  
        String = input()  
        if String == AirVar:  
                EnterTimes = EnterTimes + 1
```

Тут я пытаюсь увеличить значение переменной `EnterTimes`, где меня и ждет ошибка:

```
else:  
    EnterTimes = 0  
if EnterTimes == 5:  
    NeedStop = Yes
```

Comment: А почему она у вас определена как строка?

Comment: Соблюдайте [рекомендации по оформлению кода](https://geekbrains.ru/posts/pep8), это важнее, чем кажется на первый взгляд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете складывать (в Вашем случае - конкатенировать) строку с числом.

Почему строку? А потому что `0` в Вашем примере заключён в строковые литералы `""`:

```py
EnterTimes = "0"
```

Вы патаетесь выполнить инструкцию `"0" + 1`, что и приводит к ошибке.

Замените `"0"` на `0` и это будет работать:

```py
EnterTimes = 0
```

---

Немного общих рекомендаций:

- Используйте 4 пробела для отступов
- Не называйте переменные с заглавной буквы. Так принято именовать классы. Желательно использовать `camelCase`.
- Для бинарных структур (имеющих 2 значения, например `yes`/`no`) используйте класс `bool`
- Не ставьте пробелы перед аргументами функции
- Делайте отступы после импорта классов
- Замените 2 подряд идущих вызова `print` на 1
- Ставьте пробелы между оператором `=`
- Не инициализируйте переменные до тех пор, пока они Вам не нужны
- Называйте переменные осмысленно (это я про Ваш `String` говорю)

*Пример:*

```py
import os


enterTimes = 0
airVar = ''

print(
    'Devian Language',
    'For help type deviancommandes, tap enter 5 times to finish programm',
    sep='\n'
)

needStop = False
while not needStop:
    inp = input()
    if inp == airVar:
        EnterTimes += 1
...
```